# Use ioHook Node.js global native keyboard and mouse listener in Browser context

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, operating-system, keyboard-events

I have stacked with a tricky issue which most probably can't be solved by security limitations but you are my last chance to find a workaround.

In scope of my project I need a system which can track user mouse and keyboard actions and do it from browser (no Node.js application, no Electron, no Backend code, just pure browser capabilities).

During my investigation I found a library called ioHook https://www.npmjs.com/package/iohook which can do exactly what I need but only from Node application or from Electron shell. So my question is: can this library be somehow lunched from browser? Which literally means another question: can Node.js be lunched in browser and interact with a system as a Node application?

I found an article where author did kinda the stuff that I need: https://blog.cloudboost.io/how-to-run-node-js-apps-in-the-browser-3f077f34f8a5 but this repo is not worked for me.

Also if you know another ways how I can track mouse/keyboard events from the system (or can point me to an article where it's 100% proved that it's impossible) it will be super helpful for me!

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Ok, based on my investigation I'm ready to answer my own question.

Due to security reasons it's impossible (or close to impossible) to build global user event tracking system which works directly from browser. However it's possible to do from an Electron application together with ioHook package. It provides multi platforms capabilities and do what I need.

I wrote an article about [ioHook + Electron + WebPack integration](https://ievgeniispitsyn.medium.com/iohook-electron-webpack-integration-53c9fe010bca) and create a small [example project](https://github.com/IevgenySp/ioHookElectronWebpack)

Hope it will be helpful and saves your time!